# str.endwith() return false in valid check

Tags: python, parsing, windows-xp

**I don't need alternate solution.**

I'm using Python 2.5.4 and want know why this happens.

I write source parser for makefiles.

```
ff = open("module.mk")
f = ff.readlines()
ff.close()
for i in f:
 if ".o \\" in i[-5:]:
  print "Is %s for str: %s" %(i.endswith('.o \\'), i)
```

I got:

```
Is False for str:       bitmap.o \
```

And so for every check.

You can get module.mk from [github](https://github.com/scummvm/scummvm/blob/master/engines/access/module.mk)

Comment: There's trailing whitespace on `i`. Try `i.strip().endswith('.o \\')`. On a completely separate note, why are you still using 2.5.4?

Comment: That would make an excellent answer, @MorganThrapp.

Comment: @morgan-thrapp, mostly parser code written on my phone. Qpython on android buggy, on nokia pys60 works fine and I choose pys60. last pys60 based on 2.5.4 core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `.readlines()` it includes the newline character in the line, CR-LF in this case.

You need to remove that newline before checking `.endswith()` as such:

```
with open("module.mk") as data:    
    for i in data.readlines():
        if ".o \\" in i[-5:]:
            print "Is %s for str: %s" %(i.strip().endswith('.o \\'), i)
```

Note: The `.readlines()` call isn't needed here, I'm just keeping it in so that the behaviour remains the same as OP's code.